# How to install themes on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, themes

I've read plenty of forums and watched many videos, and yet none have worked. I just want to install Libra Dark theme on my computer (I'm new to Ubuntu), so please help me guys.

Comment: @markkirby that is kind of a lame accepted answer though because it uses ubuntu tweak tool. I included an answer that uses gnome-tweak-tool and/or unity-tweak-tool

Comment: Please see answer two of the duplicate, for an up to date solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instruction on how you can  install **"external themes"** in Ubuntu GNOME:

Download the theme and extract it to the `/home/$USER/.themes` folder.
If you haven't created this folder before, open the **Nautilus** file manager.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, click **File** from menu, select **New Folder**, name it **.themes**.

Install **GNOME Tweak Tool** - open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Open the tool and change the theme.

Comment: Thanks man it worked! I try doing the same with other themes (I extracted it to the .themes folder but nothing happened.  Is there something wrong with what I did?

Comment: @super64ds : Thanks for your feedback. I am glad that you achieved what you wanted - some themes are not compatible (GTK version) ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)